# Download selected files in knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I need to download the selected files in a grid on download button click. I am using knokout.js and web api 
Using the below given response I was able to download a single file

```
 self.DownloadDoc = function () {
    window.location.assign("http://localhost:8092/api/Document/GetResponse?id=" + self.selectedDocuments()[0]);
    self.selectedDocuments.removeAll();
    self.bindDocuments();
};
```

I tried looping this window.location.assign() code using for loop,but as it is synchronous call,its downloading only one file.

**Html part**

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click :$root.DownloadDoc,visible: $root.DownloadDocVisible"><span>Download</span><small></small></a>
```

**Web Api code**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetResponse(string id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        List<DocumentsModel> documents = _service.GetDocumentContent(Convert.ToInt32(id));
        byte[] fileBytes = documents.FirstOrDefault().FileContent;


        System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        if (fileBytes != null)
            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);

        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = mediaType;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = documents.FirstOrDefault().FileLeafRef;

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: can you paste more of code? I think there is possible issue related vith var "itemId" scope.

Comment: Is zipping your files into one not an option? If it's not then you can use `window.open(url)`.

Comment: @Adrian  Thank you. window.open(url) worked. Currently I am not looking into zip file option

Comment: I see. Good to hear it worked.

Answer (score 0):

this part `self.selectedDocuments()[0]`, looks like it will force download always only of first document. 
Not sure what is your structure and output of selectedDocuments(), 
for example, if it outputs array, with fileID nodes, maybe you should try with this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: self.selectedDocuments()">
    <a href="#" data-bind="click :$root.DownloadDoc(fileID),visible: $root.DownloadDocVisible"><span>Download</span><small></small></a>
</div>
```

then, you will have to pass param in function:

```
self.DownloadDoc = function (fileID) {
    window.location.assign("http://localhost:8092/api/Document/GetResponse?id=" + fileID);
    self.selectedDocuments.removeAll();
    self.bindDocuments();
};
```

Comment: self.selectedDocuments() is an observableArray and the id's of document will get pushed into it on selection of each document. So I am not able to give <div data-bind="foreach: self.selectedDocuments()"> with that. I tried                               for(var i=0;i<self.selectedDocuments().length;i++){  window.location.assign("http://localhost:8092/api/Document/GetResponse?id=" +self.selectedDocuments()[i] );}